# Air for Android - Is there a bug with the share via menu and invoke?

Tags: android, air, share

I'm creating a messaging app with Air for Android. 
I would like to enable other apps to share text to my app via the **share via** menu option.
My app get listed in the menu but only receives an empty string after the invokation. 
Is this a known bug?

The invoke event:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onAppInvoke);

function onAppInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
 info.text = event.arguments.toString()
}
```

The app.xml manifest:

```
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <application>             
          <activity>
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
  </intent-filter>            
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                        <data android:scheme="myapp"/> 
                    </intent-filter>
                        </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    ]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
```

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: There are no news on this. I'm still searching for a solution!